# Suggestion dropdown in text area

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

i am relatively new to nativescript, i am looking forward to implement something like friend name suggestion when we perform "@name" on facebook post comments or post description.

Is there a way i can do this using some component on nativescript?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drop-down

I am sure you will be able to find what you are looking at there. 
I am using this component in my project, still differently than what you are looking for, but this component has worked wonders for me.